# How can I edit equirectangular in JS?

Tags: javascript, 360-panorama

I need to do a feature like [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) did, but I can't find any framework or something that can help me.

So hugin is a program that helps edit equirectangulars. For example, if you took a photo from the wrong position or angle, hugin will help you change roll (offset) and resave the photo (I will attach a photo).

Did anyone see a JS library that could help me do it?

[image: image with wrong roll]

[image: image with correct roll]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Would love a lead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any library allowing for editing panorama photos. From quick research it comes aout that there are some panorama viewers like [Panolens](https://pchen66.github.io/Panolens/). It seems that it uses [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) (there is a exmaple of [equirectangular panorama](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html)). You might take a look at source codes of those and try to use similiar approach in your project.

Comment: yes i saw them, but there we have SphereBufferGeometry, but i need show equirectangulars in 2d, and find rotate matrix if roll or pitch will change